# SQL stored proc using where in statement

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to inserting data from a table to another table. But I need using multiple specific IDs in where clause. And, I need to define these IDs while running the proc. The query is below,

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_hh 
@id int
AS
BEGIN
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test_HH ON
INSERT INTO test_HH 
(ID,Beneficiary_Name,Family_Members,
[M_50_yrs],
[F_50_yrs],
[M_50_18],
[F_50_18],
[M_18_15],
[F_18_15],
[M_15_5],
[F_15_5],
[M_5_2],
[F_5_2],
[M_2],
[F_2],
Beneficiary_Status,
Reason_of_Rejection)
SELECT ID,Beneficiary_Name,Family_Members,
[M_50_yrs],
[F_50_yrs],
[M_50_18],
[F_50_18],
[M_18_15],
[F_18_15],
[M_15_5],
[F_15_5],
[M_5_2],
[F_5_2],
[M_2],
[F_2],
Beneficiary_Status,
Reason_of_Rejection 
FROM HH
WHERE ID IN ((@id))
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test_HH OFF
END
```

For now, I can insert only one ID for each time. Can you help me to insert multiple IDs in the same proc?
Thanks.

Comment: Why no just call it lots of times, in a loop maybe

Comment: Do you have those IDs list? Is the list permanent?

Comment: Incomplete question. What is @id. What will be the data type.

Comment: Sometimes need to insert lots of data as many as thousands of rows maybe. That's why I am looking for another solution instead of calling proc lots of times

Answer (score 1):

For multiple value change @Id parameter of stored procedure to VARCHAR with desired length.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_hh 
@id varchar(max)
AS
    SET @Id  = '1,10,20,30'
-- temp table
    DECLARE @Id_tbl TABLE (   Id INT )

    INSERT INTO @Id_tbl  
    SELECT 
        LTRIM(RTRIM(split.a.value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)'))) AS fqdn   
    FROM 
        (SELECT 
            CAST ('<M>' + REPLACE(@Id, ',', '</M><M>') + '</M>' AS XML) AS data   ) AS a   
            CROSS APPLY data.nodes ('/M') AS split(a)

    -- INSERT STATEMENT
    SELECT <Fields> FROM
    <Your Table>
    WHERE
        ID IN (SELECT Id FROM @Id_tbl)
END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE PROCEDURE insert_hh 
@id NVARCHAR(MAX)
AS
BEGIN
SET IDENTITY_INSERT test_HH ON

INSERT INTO test_HH 
(ID,Beneficiary_Name,Family_Members,[M_50_yrs],[F_50_yrs],[M_50_18],[F_50_18],
[M_18_15],[F_18_15],[M_15_5],[F_15_5],[M_5_2],[F_5_2],[M_2],[F_2],
Beneficiary_Status,Reason_of_Rejection)

SELECT ID,Beneficiary_Name,Family_Members,[M_50_yrs],[F_50_yrs],[M_50_18],
[F_50_18],[M_18_15],[F_18_15],[M_15_5],[F_15_5],[M_5_2],[F_5_2],[M_2],[F_2],
Beneficiary_Status,Reason_of_Rejection 

FROM HH 
CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(@id, ',') 
WHERE HH.ID = value

SET IDENTITY_INSERT test_HH OFF
END
```

[modelling fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b64718a36c383f2d19d4f9906126541e)

Pay attention - the parameter datatype is changed.

Comment: I tried it but got this error when call the proc Invalid object name 'STRING_SPLIT'.

Comment: @NisaMelisBirden Update your question and specify server version. `STRING_SPLIT` needs compatibility level 130 (SQL Server 2016).